# Metamask "Activity" can't list transactions at the recipient side!

Tags: transactions, metamask, explorers, private-ethereum

I have a private Ethereum network. A block explorer (blockscout) is connected to my miner. The problem is: using Metamask, I can send transactions, which are mined and shown in the block explorer, but the receiver cannot see them in their "Activity" tab.
The server hosting the miner and block explorer is using SSL (I have an nginx reverse proxy that directs the traffic towards rpc and the explorer).
Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the transaction use a contract?

Comment: No, these are normal P2P transactions. For those TXs that transfer other tokens based on a contract (ERC-20 based), I can see the transactions received on the other side after the token is imported properly.